# In Perl, set a variable to a regex, and I get an uninitialized value warning

Tags: regex, perl, variables, warnings

So I have this block of code, analyzing the values of parameters passed into a CGI call.

I have this block of code doing that.

```
if (defined($passed_args->{'between'})) {
    my $between = $passed_args->{'between'};
        my $date_field = @$between[0];
        my $start_date = @$between[1];
        my $end_date   = @$between[2];
        my $gdt_regex  = /[0-9]{4}(-)((0[1-9])|(1[0-2]))(-)((0[1-9])|([1-2][0-9])|(3[0-1]))(\s)(([0-1][0-9])|(2[0-3])):([0-5][0-9]):([0-5][0-9])/;

        if (!defined($passed_args->{$date_field}) && $start_date =~ $gdt_regex && $end_date =~ $gdt_regex) {
            $self->error('between parameter not populated correctly.');
            return;
        }

        $query_url .= $date_field . "BETWEEN" . $start_date . "@" . $end_date . "^";

    delete $passed_args->{'between'};

}
```

The values of start_date and end_date come in a format like so:

`2019-04-04 00:00:00`

In my server logs, I repeatedly get this warning:

`Use of uninitialized value $_ in pattern match (m//) at /my/script.pm line 6316`

Line 6316 corresponds to:

`my $gdt_regex  = /[0-9]{4}(-)((0[1-9])|(1[0-2]))(-)((0[1-9])|([1-2][0-9])|(3[0-1]))(\s)(([0-1][0-9])|(2[0-3])):([0-5][0-9]):([0-5][0-9])/;`

So as far as I know, you get that error when doing pattern matches with uninitialized values. Yet *why* am I getting it when I am *assigning a regex to a variable?* Is there something about the capture groups causing Perl to throw a fit? Or am I missing something else?

This isn't hurting anything to the best of my knowledge, but this frequently shows up in my logs, and I'd like to clear it out.

Comment: Tip: `@$between[0]` should be `$$between[0]`. (If you use `$a[0]` when using the name, you use `$$ref[0]` when using a ref.) Better yet, you should use the clearer `$between->[0]`.

Comment: Tip: The pattern should have a leading `^` and a trailing `\z` to make sure there's nothing before or after the date-tme.

Comment: Tip: All those parens you have in the pattern are causing needless capturing. You are making the pattern more complicated than it needs to be, and slower. `(-)` can be written as `-`, and you should use `(?:...)` instead of `(...)` to group alternations without capturing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`/.../` is the match operator. It checks if the pattern matches the bound variable. If no variable is explicitly bound, it matches against `$_` as if you had used `$_ =~ /.../`.

You are looking for

```
my $gdt_regex = qr/.../;
```

Answer (score 1):

well I think that some validation would be beneficial to your code

NOTE: probably `$date_start` and `date_end` would be more proper for consistency with `$date_field`

```
use strict;
use warnings;

........

if (defined($passed_args->{'between'})) {
    my($date_field,$date_start,$date_end) = @{$passed_args->{between}}[0..2];

    {
        $self->error('ERROR: between parameter not populated correctly.');
        return;
    } if ( !defined($passed_args->{$date_field}) 
        && !is_valid($date_start) 
        && !is_valid($date_end)
    ) 

    $query_url .= $date_field . "BETWEEN" . $start_date . "@" . $end_date . "^";

    delete $passed_args->{'between'};

}

#
# timestamp validation
#
sub is_valid {
    my $timestamp = shift;

    return 0 if $timestamp !~ /\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{\2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}/;

    my($date,$time)         = split ' ', $timestamp;
    my($year,$month,$day)   = split '-', $date;
    my($hour,$min,$sec)     = split ':', $time;

    #return 0 if $year  < 1900 or $year  > 2019;
    return 0 if $month < 1    or $month > 12;
    return 0 if $day   < 1    or $day   > 31;
    return 0 if $hour  < 1    or $hour  > 23;
    return 0 if $min   < 1    or $min   > 59;
    return 0 if $sec   < 1    or $sec   > 59;

    return 1;   # timestamp is valid
}
```

Comment: Your sub `is_valid` is useless, why do you limit year between `1900` and `2019`? Why don't you accept `month = 12`? Why do you accept `1900-02-29`? Use a real date time validation or don't use it.

Comment: You shouldn't use `and`/`or`/`not` unless followed by a flow control operation (`die`, `next`, `return`, etc). so `$day < 1 or $day > 31` should be `$day < 1 || $day > 31`. 1) Using `and`/`or`/`not` reduces readability. Symbols are used for `&&`/`||`/`!` for a reason. 2) `and`, `or` and `not` have very low precedence, and this will end up biting you. In fact, you had a precedence bug in you in question from using the wrong operators. (I fixed it.)

Comment: I do think the suggestion to remove the range checks from the expression is a good thing. A tad slower, but far more readable.

Comment: @Toto regex in the post accepts year from 0000 to 9999 -- it is very useful! I do not think that computer was around before 1936. Ok month 12 is valid for my verification but in perl month numbering starts at 0 - https://www.tutorialspoint.com/perl/perl_date_time.htm.

Comment: @ikegami -- well thank you for fixing, it was too late in the night when I wrote the answer. I was working on some routine project and required some diversion to take my attention away for a change -- this question was this small diversion.

Comment: @ikegami - Is it difficult to make adjustment to your 'taste'? Or this place is for 'complete solution' to not fully described problem without sample of input data? Yes, I am sure if people will not destroy this planet then there will be year 30,000 one day -- should we adjust regex for this year as well?

Comment: Please look @ OP regex once more - and then if not defined `date_field` and match regex against start and end date? Now please say to me -- if year from future will be valid as of today? My understanding is that CGI should return this year (2019 today) and next year (2020). I did not intend that my answer will be stored in some  `.pm` module in CPAN  -- my intention was to point that some extra validation could be used. It is upto originator of the post to adjust to his requirements.

Comment: Re "*if year from future will be valid as of today?*", It depends on what the dates are, so there's no way to know, so you should accept the OP's lack of check instead of potentially breaking their code. It's not like you aren't already showing them how its done. Or yeah, use a comment like you did.

Comment: @ikegami - OP refers to log files,I assume that date verification should come for current year 2019. I agree that this approach is not flexible, then check can be based on current date. Of course _date_ can be set into the future for test purpose if it is required.

Comment: The only mention of log files is when they mentioned the script is producing errors in the web server's error log. Crucially, there's no mention that the dates are from a log file, much less that the timestamps of logged events.